# k-fold nested repeated cross validation in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret

I need to do an four-fold nested repeated cross validation to train a model.
I wrote the following code, which has the inner cross-validation, but now I'm struggling to create the outer.

```
fitControl <- trainControl(## 10-fold CV
                           method = "repeatedcv",
                           number = 10,
                           ## repeated five times
                           repeats = 5,
                           savePredictions = TRUE,
                           classProbs = TRUE,
                           summaryFunction = twoClassSummary)

model_SVM_P <- train(Group ~ ., data = training_set, 
                 method = "svmPoly", 
                 trControl = fitControl,
                 verbose = FALSE,
                 tuneLength = 5)
```

I made an attempt to solve the problem:

```
ntrain=length(training_set)    
train.ext=createFolds(training_set,k=4,returnTrain=TRUE)
test.ext=lapply(train.ext,function(x) (1:ntrain)[-x])

for (i in 1:4){
    model_SVM_P <- train(Group ~ ., data = training_set[train.ext[[i]]], 
                 method = "svmRadial", 
                 trControl = fitControl,
                 verbose = FALSE,
                 tuneLength = 5) 

    }
```

But it didn't worked.
How can I do this outer loop?

Comment: This answer might prove helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62183291/statistical-test-with-test-data/62193116#62193116. The problem in your code is you create `model_SVM_P` four times for each `i` instead of saving results of the four iterations in a list for example.

Comment: I tried to add the result in a list, but It doesn't work. How can I create a list of objects? model_SVM_P class is "train" and "train.function", I couldn't find a way to create a list of these elements

Comment: You can just use the `lapply` approach in the linked post. To learn how to use `for` loops in R read this: https://r4ds.had.co.nz/iteration.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rsample` package has implemented the outer loop in the `nested_cv()` function, see [documentation](https://rsample.tidymodels.org/reference/nested_cv.html).

To evaluate the models trained by nested_cv, have a look at this [vignette](https://www.tidymodels.org/learn/work/nested-resampling/) which shows where the "heavylifting" is done:

```
# `object` is an `rsplit` object in `results$inner_resamples` 
summarize_tune_results <- function(object) {
  # Return row-bound tibble that has the 25 bootstrap results
  map_df(object$splits, tune_over_cost) %>%
    # For each value of the tuning parameter, compute the 
    # average RMSE which is the inner bootstrap estimate. 
    group_by(cost) %>%
    summarize(mean_RMSE = mean(RMSE, na.rm = TRUE),
              n = length(RMSE),
              .groups = "drop")
}

tuning_results <- map(results$inner_resamples, summarize_tune_results)
```

This code applies the `tune_over_cost` function on every hyperparameter and split (or fold) of the training data which is here called "assessment data".

Please check out the vignette for more useful code including parallelization.